# Bootsrap date picker selecting end date based on start date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the following to disable previous dates based on start date

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

it is working fine but I observed a weird behavior as follows, on the initial run when I select check-in date as today's date it is working fine. If I modify to and forth by changing the check-out date and check-in date this is what I observed
[image]

So can some one help me what I need to change

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this component, but I guess it should be something like this:

```
$('#idOfTheDatePicker').datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(ev){
        $('#idOfTheEndDatePicker').datepicker('setValue' 'TIME')
    });
```

`TIME` can be a string or a Date object. I think everything is in the lower section of the page you linked in your question

Comment: What about the code on the example, doesn't it work? As I said, I have not tested anything